# LGHT0309 : Failed to open merge module for validation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, multilingual, light

What means the follow error message? I receive it after I add the "Languages" attribute to "Package" tag with an list of IDs like described in http://www.geektieguy.com/2010/03/13/create-a-multi-lingual-multi-language-msi-using-wix-and-custom-build-scripts/

> light.exe : error LGHT0309 : Failed to open merge module for
>   validation. The most common cause of this error is specifying that the
>   merge module supports multiple languages (using the Package/@Languages
>   attribute) but not including language-specific embedded transforms. To
>   fix this error, make the merge module language-neutral, make it
>   language-specific, embed language transforms as specified in the MSI
>   SDK at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa367799.aspx, or disable
>   validation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be wrong to set the Languages via the *.wix file with the current WIX version. You need to:

- create the msi file
- add (embedded) the translations
- set the language IDs in the msi file

A good description can you find here: https://www.hass.de/content/how-create-msi-packages-multilingual-user-interface-mui

Comment: And thats exactly the reason, why i was asking you to make the merge module language neutral by setting the Languages attribute to 0. I was just about to get there when you found it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. 
In your source file for the merge module, what value do you have for the Module/Package@Languages attribute?

The error also suggests that you can fix this by making the Languages attribute to 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How I have write. I have add a list of IDs to the "Languages" attribute. What else the compiler want to accept this?

Comment: Make the value 0 in the Languages attribute.  What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to build a multi language merge module? Kindly let us know so that an appropriate answer can be provided.

Comment: Yes, the final target is a multi languages installer.